# Formatted Excel using XML

Tags: excel, xml

I need to have XML that can be opened in Excel. The XML should contained Excel cell styles as well. To see How the xml looks like what i do is simply save the Excel sheet as 'XML Spreadsheet 2003 (*.xml).

- Is this the way or there are other newer formats?
- Can anyone point me to the documentation of this format?

with best regards,
rnv

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the requirement? This sounds to me like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because a tabular format such as Excel isn't a great way of representing hierarchical data formats such as XML.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Office Open XML format](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/)?